# How to take elements of a list to create individuals sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create sublist from a big list in the way:

```
data = {{1., 0.18133, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148461, 0.148461}, {3., 0.121549, 0.121549},
 {4., 0.0995161, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814769, 0.0814769}, {1., 0.180988, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148243, 0.148461},
 {3., 0.121423, 0.121549}, {4., 0.0994543, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814604, 0.0814769}}
```

and I want to create sublists:

```
sub1 = {{1., 0.18133, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148461, 0.148461},
 {3., 0.121549, 0.121549}, {4., 0.0995161, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814769, 0.0814769}}

sub2 = {{1., 0.180988, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148243, 0.148461},
 {3., 0.121423, 0.121549}, {4., 0.0994543, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814604, 0.0814769}}
```

and so on, in order to manipulate each list separately. Until now I used:
`Take[data, n]` and `Partition[data, n]` but I can not use the sublist in an independent way.

Comment: Please supply real data the people could experiment with, not some vague abbreviated form. Also supply a clear example of what the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{1., 0.18133, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148461, 0.148461}, {3., 
    0.121549, 0.121549}, {4., 0.0995161, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814769, 
    0.0814769}, {1., 0.180988, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148243, 
    0.148461}, {3., 0.121423, 0.121549}, {4., 0.0994543, 
    0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814604, 0.0814769}};

Evaluate@ToExpression@
   Table["sub" <> ToString@i, {i, Length@Partition[data, 5]}] = 
 Partition[data, 5];
```

Then

```
sub1
```

> {{1., 0.18133, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148461, 0.148461}, {3., 0.121549, 
>     0.121549}, {4., 0.0995161, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814769, 0.0814769}}

```
sub2
```

> {{1., 0.180988, 0.18133}, {2., 0.148243, 0.148461}, {3., 0.121423, 
>     0.121549}, {4., 0.0994543, 0.0995161}, {5., 0.0814604, 0.0814769}}

---

Or just simply

```
sub = Partition[data, 5];
```

and you can refer to sublists of `sub` via `Part`:

```
sub[[1]]
sub[[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {n, m}}, {{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {n, m}}}
Table[Evaluate[ToExpression["sub" <> ToString@i]] = data[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]

sub1
(*Out[]={{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {n, m}}*)
```